# Reading Gmail from Protractor

Tags: angularjs, email, gmail, protractor

I have a protractor test that uses mailinator for check if I am receiving some mails but I would like to use Gmail instead.

My test looks like this:

In my down-mail.js:

```
function findEmailBySubject(subject) {

console.log("searching");
var emails = element.all(by.repeater('email in emails')).all(by.binding('email.subject'));

var theOne;

emails.map(function (item) {
    return item.getText();
}).then(function (names) {
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        console.log(names[i]);
        //console.log(theOne);
        if (names[i].indexOf(subject) != -1) {
            theOne = i;
            console.log('Found alert email in position: ' + theOne);
        }
    }
    // the email should be in the list:
    expect(theOne).not.toBeUndefined();

});
}

function deleteAlertEmails() {

console.log('Deleting all emails');

var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow()

var emails;

emails = element.all(by.repeater('email in emails')).all(by.binding('email.subject'));

emails.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);

    for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {           
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.driver.sleep(1000);
        emails = element.all(by.repeater('email in emails')).all(by.binding('email.subject'));

        emails.map(function (email) {
            return email;
        }).then(function (items) {
            items[0].click();

            // and some more waits after the click...
            browser.waitForAngular();
            browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            element(by.partialButtonText('Delete')).click();
        });
    }

   });



 }

describe('Referee', function() {
it('should send an email notification on failure of a check', function() {

    var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow()

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    // start by deleting all old mails:
    console.log("0. First we delete all emails from the inbox");
    deleteAlertEmails();


    // First delete the file that is in S3, so the check will fail
    console.log("1. Now delete the file from S3");
    flow.await(deleteFile(s3)).then(function() {
        console.log('File deleted');
        // Wait for 1.5 minute to give it time to see that the file is not there and send a mail
        console.log("waiting for the DOWN mail...");

        // using browser.wait(condition)
        flow.await(browser.driver.sleep(60000)).then(function() {

            console.log("waited");
            // wait for angular:
            browser.waitForAngular();
            console.log("angular ready");

            // Search for the alert email:
            console.log("2. Search for the alert email");
            findEmailBySubject("DOWN - An S3 test file");

            // Now put the file back:
            console.log("3. Now put the file back");
            flow.await(uploadFile(s3)).then(function() {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + FILE_NAME);
  //                    // wait 15 seconds
 //                    browser.driver.sleep(15000);

                console.log("waiting for the UP mail...");
                // wait to make sure the UP email is sent
                flow.await(browser.driver.sleep(60000)).then(function() {


                // Search for the alert email:
                console.log("4. Search for the UP email");
                findEmailBySubject("UP - An S3 test file");

                // and now delete all the alert emails:
                console.log("5. Now delete all the emails from the inbox");
                deleteAlertEmails();

                });

            }, function(err) {
                console.log("ERROR uploading file to S3");
                throw new Error(err);
            });
        });


    }, function(err) {
        console.log('ERROR deleting file - stopping here');
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error(err);
    });


   });




   });
```

This is my local-config.js file:

```
 exports.config = {
 seleniumAddress: '',
 specs: ['down-mail.js'],
 onPrepare: function() {
 browser.driver.get('http://www.mailinater.com/inbox.jsp?to=juanazensie');
 },
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
 onComplete: null,
 isVerbose: true,
 showColors: true,
 includeStackTrace: true,
 defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
 }
};
```

I would like to know please if is it possible to do this with the Gmail API and read these mails from Gmail using Protractor?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: According to @Oleskii in a more recent post, the answer is yes. Did you solve this? I know the answer to the question would be "yes" and SO is not for doing other people's job's, but it would be really helpful if one of you could post the actual code as an answer here. Or this appears to be solved at https://gist.github.com/pittgoose/f29a653b8cac18fe794169ef40c2a24b